# What are good resources for learning predicate logic / predicate calculus?

Tags: logic

I'm trying to learn predicate logic.

And I'm looking for some good resources on it:

I've seen that I learn better when I can program
So I was wondering if there was a 'predicate logic' programning language?

Maybe an interactive tutorial?

Maybe lots of examples, something like: Predicate Logic by Example?

Or at least some pretty basic books?

TIA

Comment: Community Wiki!

Answer (score 5):

[Introduction to Logic: Predicate Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131649892) by Pospesel is the text probably most frequently associated with the topic for introductory students from a purely academic perspective.

If you really want to code in languages that are based around predicate logic (logic programming is the more formal term), there are a few options:

- Prolog is easily the best known and without a doubt the best documented logic programming language
- Oz is a lesser known alternative that incorporates a number of more modern programming language features like concurrency and object orientation (modern Prolog implementations typically add some of these to the language, but it never seems a natural fit to the language)
- Castor is a fairly common library for C++ that builds a logic model within the syntax of C++

Comment: Curry is another option if you are interested in logic programming. It's an integrated logic and (pure) functional programming language.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of good books on symbolic logic, [Understanding Symbolic Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132051524) being one.

However, there aren't many of them using a "programming" approach, [Haskell Road to Logic, Maths, and programming](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~jve/HR/) being such a gem.