# What are the names given to statements that can be true or false?

Tags: logic, terminology

While compiling a set of notes for high school students about logic and proof, I wrote

> Let $A$ and $B$ be statements. Then $A \Rightarrow B$ means ''if $A$ is true then $B$ is true.''

This was my definition of a statement:

> A *(mathematical) statement* is a sentence that is either definitely true or definitely false. (It cannot, therefore represent an opinion, like "apples taste better than bananas" or events that may or may not be true, like "It will rain tomorrow in London".) Statements can therefore be proved/disproved by providing an argument that rigorously demonstrates that they are true/false.

By the above definition, $A$ and $B$ don't have to be statements for $A \Rightarrow B$ to make sense. For instance, for real $x$, "$x>4 \Rightarrow x>2$" makes sense (and is true) and yet it isn't possible to assign a definite true/false value to these sub-statements "$x>4$" and "$x>2$" in isolation.

This leads me to my question: is there a proper name for things like "$x>2$" and "$x>4$", where it makes grammatical sense to call them true or false, but which cannot truly be called either, without being given more information?

I was thinking of calling them boolean phrases, but I would rather not just invent a name for something if a proper name is already in use. Another option is just to redefine what I call a (mathematical) statement to include this kind of thing, but then add another definition like "decidable statement" to describe sentences that are either definitely true or definitely false.

This question also applies to other examples. What name should be given to sentences like the below?

- "This sentence is false" (seems like it can be true or false, but both lead to contradictions)
- "$x$ is even" (We cannot decide if it's true or false without more information about $x$)

Comment: ''$x >4 \Rightarrow x>2$" is not a statement because its value of truth cannot be established as $x$ is not specified. Instead ''$\forall x \in \Bbb R, x >4 \Rightarrow x>2$" is a statement, and you can prove it's true. See the difference between predicates and propositions for example [at this link](https://cse.buffalo.edu/~xinhe/cse191/Classnotes/note02-1x2#:~:text=A%20predicate%20is%20a%20function,have%20any%20variable%20as%20argument.)

Comment: I've purposely avoided using $\forall$ since this discussion is aimed at high-school students. But I see your point. To clarify, are you saying $x>4$ is an example of predicate?

Comment: Is ‘statement’ being used in the same way as ‘sentence’?

Comment: Yes, $x>4$ is an example of a predicate. The term you are looking for is *predicate*.

Comment: @PW _246 The definition of a statement is given, a "sentence" is a more informal notion of basically a pile of words which makes sense. I'm not sure if that's what you meant

Comment: You might be interested in [the difference between propositional logic and predicate logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9554/whats-the-difference-between-predicate-and-propositional-logic).

Comment: Also see [well-formed formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_formula).

Comment: [Propositional function](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/propositional-function/).

Comment: By the way, what do you consider the problem with "It will rain tomorrow in London"? Statements about the future still make sense as long as all the terminology is properly defined. What matters is that the truth criteria are clear.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you know whether or not $x\gt 2$. What's important is that it is either true or false. It's called a proposition. A "sentence" by definition has no free variables so to convert a proposition with free variables to a sentence we must use quantifiers.

Comment: If the truth of a proposition depends on the variable, then it's called an open sentence

Comment: @Karl I want statements to basically be "provable or disprovable claims", so they have to be definitely true or definitely false, not e.g. true with probability 0.6 and false with probability 0.4.

Comment: "Provable or disprovable" might be too strong a requirement in light of [Godel's incompleteness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems).

Comment: I call $x > 4$ a formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for real $x$, "$x>4 \Rightarrow x>2$" is true yet it isn't possible to assign a definite true/false value to its sub-statements "$x>4$" and "$x>2$" in isolation. is there a proper name for things like "$x>2$" and "$x>4$"?

For every real $x,$ the **predicate** $$x>4 \to x>2$$ is true. In other words, the **statement** $$\forall x\:(x>4 \to x>2)$$ is true. [Every predicate contains a free variable, whereas every statement contains none.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4231999/21813)

> A **statement** is a sentence that is **either definitely true or definitely false**.

$(x=x)$ is ***not*** technically a statement, but it ***is*** definitely true.

$(\forall x \;x^2\le0)$ ***is*** a statement, but—being true in the universe of imaginary numbers but false in the universe comprises of real numbers—it is arguably ***neither*** definitely true ***nor*** definitely false. (To be fair: it definitely is either true or false).

Comment: Thank you! Would I be correct in saying that with the definition that I used, $\forall x, \, x^2\leq 0 $ is still a predicate since $x$ is still not properly specified; it needs to say $\forall x \in $[some set]?

Comment: @James $(\forall x \;x^2\le0)$
 is not a predicate simply because it contains no free variable; your "[some set]" is just the domain of discourse, which is always at least tacitly dependent on the context; if your concern is about "definitely" assigning a truth value, then notice that $(\forall x \;x^2\le0)$'s truth value actually depends also on how we interpret the non-logical symbol $≤.$

Answer (score 2):

You're being sabotaged here by your book's imprecise language.  $A$ and $B$ are statements.  But the *symbols* “$A$” and “$B$” are not statements, they are symbols that represent statements.

This is similar to algebra: “$x$” is not a number.  It is a letter ‘x’, used as a symbol that *represents* a number.  The number itself is $x$.  Or a more familiar example: you are not “James”, because “James” is a five-letter word, and you are not a word, you are a person. You are James, not “James”.  “James” is only your name.

When the book says:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be statements. Then $A⇒B$ means ''if $A$ is true then $B$ is true''

it is, strictly speaking, incorrect, since, as you observed, $A$ and $B$ are not statements.  A more careful writer would have put it like this:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be statements. Then the formula consisting of the statement $A$, followed by the symbol “$⇒$”, followed by the statement $B$, means that if $A$ is true then $B$ is true.

Maybe you can see why this is rarely done.  (Even this is not correct. Instead of “statement” it should say “formula”.)

In contexts where the author really does want to deal carefully with these distinctions, they often adopt a notation called *quasiquotation* in which the long phrase

> the formula consisting of the statement $A$, followed by the symbol “$⇒$”, followed by the statement $B$

is abbreviated to

> $⸢A⇒B⸣$

with the square quote notation having been defined to have the desired meaning.  You can find this, for example, in Quine's book *Mathematical Logic*.  There might also be something about it in [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quotation/), but I did not check.

I don't know if this helps you in writing your notes for high school students, but you should at least be clear in your mind about the distinction between names of things and things themselves, or else you will pass on your confusion to your students.

I'm reluctant to complicate the explanation even more, but there is another layer of confusion, which is that $A$ and $B$ should be said to be *formulas*, not statements.  Formulas are sequences of symbols that, if well-formed, may *represent* statements.  The neither-true-nor-false formulas you mention, such as “$x<1$”, are called *open formulas*. As you observed, an open formula is not a statement.  Open formulas can be turned into *closed formulas* that do represent statements, by *binding* the *free variables*. In “$x<1$"  the free variable is “$x$”.  When we bind $x$ we get a formula like

> $\forall x. x<1$,

which represents the statement “Every $x$ is less than $1$”, or

> $\exists x. x<1$,

which represents the statement “There is some $x$ that is less than $1$”

Comment: I think this is the most precise (and correct) response to the question, but I equally doubt that most high school students would understand it... A bit toooo subtle, and does not refer to real issues involving things connected to their normal lives. Still, saying "you are not (the word) 'James', you're James" might catch their fancy.

Comment: (Btw, I did really enjoy your Perl book! :)

Comment: If I were in your position, I would avoid the “$A\to B$ is not a formula” issue completely, as almost everyone does. Instead I would try hard to use the terminology right, between formulas (well-formed sequences of symbols), sentences (closed formulas), and statements (true or false claims that can be asserted by sentences). Using these correctly and uniformly would help everyone understand better. When they got confused, you would be able to use the terminology to help sort them out.  And thanks for your kind words about the book!